# Using a .txt to receive inputs in a C program

Tags: c, input

I am not even sure to begin with this, but essentially instead of running my program with user input, I would like to use a .txt to receive and store my inputs.

So for example the .txt file is presented as so:

1 2 3

5 6

8 9 10

How would I open this .txt file and store each individual number as variables within my program?

Comment: ...use `FILE` IO functions? Or, if you already read from stdin, you could just redirect a file when running the program. A book or online tutorial may be a better place to start with this. Then you can ask more specific questions.

Comment: fopen,fread/fscanf, blah blah blah

Comment: @Alex G, once you have found an answer that answers your question you should click the check mark next that post.

Comment: @Alex G-The system calls like read , open, write, close, lseek provide  
an easy way to work with files.
But certainly you have to learn about file i/o to do what you want   
to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of these assume the sample input you provided.  Adjusting to a different arrangement of inputs is left as an exercise for the reader...

Just about the simplest possible program to do that (assumes you run with: ./myprogram < myfile.txt)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void ) {

    int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h;          /* terrible variable names */

    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
    scanf("%d %d", &d, &e);
    scanf("%d %d %d", &f, &g, &h);

    return 0;
}
```

Next step, reading from a named file:

```
int main ( void ) {

    FILE * fp;
    int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h;          /* terrible variable names */

    fp = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
    fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &d, &e);
    fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", &f, &g, &h);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Note the changes.  Next step in making this better would be to obtain the file name from the command line.

```
int main ( int argc, char * argv[] ) {

    FILE * fp;
    int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h;          /* terrible variable names */
    char * filename;

    if (argc > 1) filename = argv[1];
    else {
         fprintf(stderr, "please supply an input filename on the command line\n");
         return 2;
    }
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    /* and then continues as in the version above... */
}
```

Again note the changes.

Comment: Hard coding the fscanfs to perfectly match the input file isn't very portable. Consider using a while loop such as exemplified in my answer.

Comment: That would be another refinement -- trying to do this in baby steps... (also, other data input arrangements might not lend themselves to a looping input paradigm).

Answer (score 0):

To use text as an input into a terminal-based program, type the following into the terminal:

```
programExecutable < textInput.txt
```

where programExecutable is your compiled program and textInput.txt is the file you want to use as an input.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want something like config files. This is a simple example

http://www.pacificsimplicity.ca/blog/simple-read-configuration-file-struct-example

Answer (score 0):

In C, you could do this using file handles and storing the read data into an array. So you would have something as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_NUMBER 100

int main()
{
    FILE *inputFile;
    inputFile = fopen("yourDataFile.txt", "r");
    int input[MAX_NUMBER];
    int i = 0;

    while (!feof(inputFile) && i<MAX_NUMBER) {
        fscanf(inputFile, "%d", input[i]); 
        i++;
    }

fclose(inputFile);
}
```

Here is a link to more documentation: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

Comment: probably want to give input a size (and then make sure you don't read more values than that...)